# What is the fastest way to send details to google analytics from an API

Tags: php, sockets, curl, google-analytics

My API currently sends analytics tracking via a cURL request, however, this really slows down the amount of requests that the API can handle, so I tried sending it via socket instead and ignoring the output, however analytics doesn't seem to be tracking it.

I've attached both sets of code below, when the curl one is used I can see it show up immediately in analytics real time, when the socket one is used real time analytics doesn't really seem to change.

I'm not sure if there is an error in the code for the socket one or if google analytics just doesn't like it for some reason, any ideas?

Socket code:

```
private function track() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])) {
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
    }   
    $url = 'www.google-analytics.com';
    $page = '/collect';
    $fields = array(
        'v' => '1',
        'tid' => $this->GA_ID,
        'cid' => $this->gaParseCookie(),
        't' => 'pageview',
        'dh' => 'webservice.fanart.tv',
        'dp' => $this->ttype.' - '.$_GET["api_key"].' - '.$this->project,
        'dt' => $this->tid,
        'uip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    );
    $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
    $fp = fsockopen($url, 80, $errno, $errstr, 5);
    $output = "POST $page HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $output .= "Host: $url\r\n";
    $output .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $output .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($fields_string)."\r\n";
    $output .= "Connection: close\r\n";
    $output .= $fields_string;
    fwrite($fp, $output);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Curl code:

```
private function track() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])) {
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
    }   
    $url = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/collect';
    $fields = array(
        'v' => '1',
        'tid' => $this->GA_ID,
        'cid' => $this->gaParseCookie(),
        't' => 'pageview',
        'dh' => 'webservice.fanart.tv',
        'dp' => $this->ttype.' - '.$_GET["api_key"].' - '.$this->project,
        'dt' => $this->tid,
        'uip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
    );
    $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsurprisingly it was a simple error in the end.

```
$output .= "Connection: close\r\n";
$output .= $fields_string;
```

needs to be

```
$output .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
$output .= $fields_string;
```

After that tracking started working

Additionally I found on some hosts looking up the hostname was causing it to slow down, after saving the IP in memcache the cheap VPS I was unit testing it on went from averaging 15 requests a second to around 1,000 requests a second.

The updated working code is as follows:

```
public function track() {
    $url = 'www.google-analytics.com';
    $page = '/collect';
    $googleip = $this->memcacheget('googleip');
    if(empty($googleip)) {
        $googleip = gethostbyname($url);
        $this->memcacheset('googleip', $googleip, 3600);
    }


    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])) {
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
    }   

    $fields = array(
        'v' => '1',
        'tid' => $this->GA_ID,
        'cid' => $this->gaParseCookie(),
        't' => 'pageview',
        'dh' => 'webservice.fanart.tv',
        'dp' => $this->ttype.' - '.$_GET["api_key"].' - '.$this->project,
        'dt' => $this->tid,
        'uip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'ua' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
    );

    $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
    $fp=fsockopen($googleip, 80, $errno, $errstr, 5);

    stream_set_blocking($fp, 0);
    stream_set_timeout($fp, 5);

    $output = "POST http://".$url.$page." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $output .= "Host: $url\r\n";
    $output .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($fields_string)."\r\n";
    $output .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    $output .= $fields_string;

    $sentData = 0;
    $toBeSentData = strlen($output);
    while($sentData < $toBeSentData) {
        $sentData += fwrite($fp, $output);
    }

    fclose($fp);
}

public function memcacheget($key){
    $memcache = new Memcache;
    $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
    $result = $memcache->get($key);
    return $result;
}

public function memcacheset($key,$value,$timeout=86400){
    $memcache = new Memcache;
    $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
    //$memcache->flush();
    $result = $memcache->get($key);
    if(empty($result)){  //store in memcache
        $memcache->set($key,$value,MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED,$timeout);
    } else {
        $memcache->replace($key,$value,MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED,$timeout);
    }
    return $result;
}
```